# Automatically getting implementation contract for eip 1967 proxy

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, storage, proxy-contracts

Let's say I wanted to write code which looks at a smart contract, detects whether it is an upgradeable proxy, and then fetches the contract address.

Something like so:

```
const functionNames = abi.map((func) => func.name)
const isEip1967 = ((functionNames.includes('implementation')) && (functionNames.includes('upgradeTo')))

if (isEip1967) {
    const implementation = contract.getImplementation()
}
```

Now, this fails, as under Eip1967, only the contract admin has the rights to call the `implementation` function. Looking at an example eip 1967 proxy (https://etherscan.io/address/0x777777c9898d384f785ee44acfe945efdff5f3e0#writeContract),

the notes on the implementation function say:

```
Returns the current implementation. NOTE: 
Only the admin can call this function. See {ProxyAdmin-getProxyImplementation}. 
TIP: To get this value clients can read directly from the storage slot shown below (specified by EIP1967) 
using the https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getstorageat[`eth_getStorageAt`] RPC call. 
`0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc`
```

Fine, so far so good. Is there a way to get this storage address for an arbitrary eip1967 smart contract, so that I can write an automatic script to fetch implementation contracts?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fetch the implementation contracts off most EIP-1967 proxies at the storage slot `0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc` since this is the standard. See EIP-1967 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1967.

So basically it's `eth_getStorageAt` and then `0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc`, and it'll return the implementation address.

Here's an example with web3js v4+ for Uniswap V3 proxy https://etherscan.io/address/0xEe6A57eC80ea46401049E92587E52f5Ec1c24785

```
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

// Put a node endpoint to do the call
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('NODE_ENDPOINT'));

// Fixed storage slot for the implementation address as per EIP-1967
const IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = '0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc';

async function getImplementationAddress(proxyAddress) {
    // Do eth_getStorageAt and then the default storage slot
    const implAddress = await web3.eth.getStorageAt(proxyAddress, IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT);

    return implAddress;
}

const proxyAddress = '0xEe6A57eC80ea46401049E92587E52f5Ec1c24785';
getImplementationAddress(proxyAddress).then(console.log);
```

This is just a read call. You don't have to be an admin (or do a transaction) to do the call.